# thread safe std::queue class c++17

Tags: c++, queue, thread-safety, c++17

queue_safe.cpp

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

#include "queue_safe.h"

void SafeQueue::initialize() {

    /* initialize a std::queue */

    safe_queue = {};
    
}

std::string SafeQueue::get() {

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> condition_lock(queue_lock);

    /* wait 20 seconds */

    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point wait = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::system_clock::duration(20);

    while (safe_queue.empty()) {

        if (ready.wait_until(condition_lock, wait) == std::cv_status::timeout) {

            /* timeout was reached, no items left */

            std::cout << "no items left in queue..." << std::endl;
        }

        std::string element = safe_queue.front();

        safe_queue.pop();

        return element;
    }

    /* not empty, return an element */
    
    std::string element = safe_queue.front();

    safe_queue.pop();

    return element;

}

void SafeQueue::put(std::string& element) {

    /* does not need to be thread-safe */

    safe_queue.push(element);

}

uint8_t SafeQueue::empty() {

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> condition_lock(queue_lock);
    
    if (safe_queue.size() == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

queue_safe.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>

class SafeQueue {
public:
    std::condition_variable ready;
    std::mutex queue_lock;

    std::queue<std::string> safe_queue;
    uint8_t empty();
    void initialize();
    void put(std::string& element);
    std::string get();
};
```

This shows my code to safely get a string from a queue. I want to wait 20 seconds max for an element to become available, so i use a condition variable, a unique lock, and lastly `wait_until`. as far as I know, I dont need a mutex around the push (add) function.
Goal: Create a thread-safe queue that times out after a designated period (20 seconds here).
Questions: Is this really thread safe? Do i need a mutex/guard around the push function, if so, why?
Okay, so 1) i need to use bool instead of unsigned ints for readability purposes, 2) I need to sync push and pop, 3) the time point is not truly 20 seconds. 4) I need to handle 'spurious wakeups'

Comment: Does `std::chrono::system_clock::duration` always represent seconds?

Comment: `wait_until` needs to either have a predicate, or be in a loop to handle spurious wake ups. This also avoids problems with a wait possibly racing and missing a notify signal. A lock and a condition variable alone are not enough to implement a complete wait mechanism.

Comment: ```Class template std::chrono::duration represents a time interval.

It consists of a count of ticks of type Rep and a tick period, where the tick period is a compile-time rational constant representing the number of seconds from one tick to the next. ``` from: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration the wait_until function takes this specific type in instead of something like a plain integer @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: The number of seconds from one tick to the next is probably a lot less than 1.

Comment: It's being hinted above that `std::chrono::system_clock::duration(20)` likely does not mean "20 seconds".  You probably meant `std::chrono::seconds(20)`.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely need to synchronize your `push` with your `pop`. Both of those modify the queue, so they cannot occur concurrently.

Comment: Please explain why you think you `"don't need a mutex around the push (add) function"`.

Comment: When you timeout on `get` your function simply proceeds as-if it hadn't timed out and tries to pop an element anyway. This is a programming error.

Comment: In C++, prefer `bool` to represent yes/no values rather than a `uint8_t`. Using `uint8_t` and other integer types to represent yes/no was born from the absence of a `bool` type in C, but that does not apply to C++.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux hmm, simply proceeds? the while loop is only executed if the queue IS empty and therefore, the code below the loop would not be executed. the print statement is so i can see what im doing/I understand i need to return there or similar else the code below the loop will execute. Should have commented that there so that was understood to begin with,

Comment: @noah The code **inside** the loop is executed.

Comment: @noah There is no branch in which your `get` function doesn't `safe_queue.pop();`. No matter what, it `pop`s regardless of whether or not the queue is empty.

Comment: Regarding the edit, you also need 5) to `notify` in `put` otherwise the condition variable is glorified sleep.

Answer (score 2):

> as far as I know, I dont need a mutex around the push (add) function.

You know wrong.

> Is this really thread safe?

No.

> Do i need a mutex/guard around the push function

Yes.

> why?

Because unsequenced modification of the container results in undefined behaviour. `std::queue::push` modifies the container.